# MySQL Workbench Snap To Grid

Tags: macos, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 5.2.36 in OS X and was wondering where in the options is the Snap To Grid function when editing a model?

I can find Show Grid, but that's all... it's sort of pointless without snapping.

The strange part is that I had this feature enabled at some point but I can not seem to find it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, I find the answer to my own question just a few moments after publicly asking for help.

If anyone else can't find what is called "snap to grid" in every other program, it's because, in MySQL Workbench, it's called "Align to Grid"... silly me:

[image]